# StreamReader shows content on WriteLine function but return empty if using it in a variable

Tags: c#, streamreader

Can somebody help me solving this? When I use the reader on WriteLine it writes the message perfectly, but when I try to save as a variable too, it return an empty string. I'm doing this because I want to save the log on a file afterwards.

```
using (var stream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream())
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    Console.WriteLine("Username: " + usernames[i]);
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
                    content = reader.ReadToEnd().ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine(content);
                    Console.WriteLine("URL: https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/users/" + usernames[i] + "\n");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reader reads in one direction: forward. If you want to read the same value twice, you have to back up and read it again.

Modify your code as follows:

```
using (var stream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    Console.WriteLine("Username: " + usernames[i]);
    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());

    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    content = reader.ReadToEnd().ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(content);
    Console.WriteLine("URL: https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/users/" + usernames[i] + "\n");
```

Comment: My stream.Seek gives an error: Specified method is not supported

Comment: @PedroWilliam: If your stream doesn't support seeking, you can't read the same value twice.  At all.  So save the result of the first `reader.ReadToEnd()` to a variable and then use that variable twice.

Comment: You're an angel!!! Thank you so much. Saved to a variable first and it worked.